# I can't retrieve JSON data array from php page to another

Tags: javascript, php, json

```
<?php
require_once './db_connect.php';
    $db = new DB_Connect();
    $db->connect();
$data = json_decode($_POST['myData']);

 $array=json_decode($_REQUEST['question']);


 if(isset($_POST['myData'])){
 $obj = json_decode($_POST['myData']);
 //some php operation


 $q = "insert into questions(question)
    values ('". $obj."')";


    $result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

I want to retrieve the JSON data that is being sent from another php page to this page , but I just can't ,,why is that ?

here's the other page

```
    function validateForm()
    {
        var q = document.forms["form1"]["question"].value;
        var T = document.forms["form1"]["title"].value;
        if (T == null || T == "")
        {
            alert("please type you form title first");
            return false;
        }
        if (q == null || q == "")
        {
            document.getElementById("question").style.color="black";
            alert("please enter your question");
            return false;
        }

        question.push(q);
        //alert(JSON.stringify(question));

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('post', 'create_form.php',true);

// Track the state changes of the request
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    // Ready state 4 means the request is done
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
        // 200 is a successful return
        if(xhr.status === 200){
            alert(xhr.responseText); // 'This is the returned text.'
        }else{
            alert('Error: '+xhr.status); // An error occurred during the request
        }
    }
}

// Send the request to send-ajax-data.php
xhr.send({myData:JSON.stringify(question)}); //+encodeURI(JSON.stringify(question))
      //  addField();

        return true;
    }
```

can someone please help me ?? 
I'm tried to solve this using jquery ajax , it's just the same ,, that's why i tried to use only javascript to solve this

Comment: Have you checked on firebug or chrome dev console that ajax request send or not ?? And Please do var_dump($_POST) or print_r($_POST) on server side to know data included or not.

Comment: yes I did ,both things , but when I alert the value

alert(JSON.stringify(myData:JSON.stringify(question)));

it gives me the html code that I have in the page !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

instead of this

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['myData']);

 $array=json_decode($_REQUEST['question']);


 if(isset($_POST['myData'])){
 $obj = json_decode($_POST['myData']);
```